# Creating parent child nodes using liner xml structure XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to transform a liner XML structure in to parent child structure.
liner XML structure is :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<MESSAGE>
  <ORDER>
   <NAME>HEADER</NAME>
   <ORDER_NO>100</ORDER_NO>
   <ADDRESS>Posted</ADDRESS>
  </ORDER>
  <ORDER>
   <NAME>DETAIL</NAME>
    <LINE_NO>1</LINE_NO>
   <QTY>1</QTY>
  </ORDER>
  <ORDER>
   <NAME>DETAIL</NAME>
   <QTY>1</QTY>
   <LINE_NO>2</LINE_NO>
  </ORDER>
  <ORDER>
   <NAME>DETAIL</NAME>
   <QTY>2</QTY>
   <LINE_NO>3</LINE_NO>
  </ORDER>
  <ORDER>
   <NAME>HEADER</NAME>
   <ORDER_NO>200</ORDER_NO>
   <ADDRESS>Posted</ADDRESS>
  </ORDER>
   <ORDER>
   <NAME>DETAIL</NAME>
   <QTY>3</QTY>
   <LINE_NO>1</LINE_NO>
  </ORDER>
  <ORDER>
   <NAME>DETAIL</NAME>
   <LINE_NO>1</LINE_NO>
   <QTY>3</QTY>
  </ORDER>
</MESSAGE>
```

each  node has a  item which distinguishes that the node is header or detail. e.g element with NAME =DETAIL is a detail node and NAME = HEADER is considered as header.

output xml should look like

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<MESSAGE>
  <ORDER>
   <NAME>HEADER</NAME>
   <ORDER_NO>100</ORDER_NO>
   <ADDRESS>Posted</ADDRESS>
       <ORDER_LINE>
       <NAME>DETAIL</NAME>
        <LINE_NO>1</LINE_NO>
       <QTY>1</QTY>
      </ORDER_LINE>
      <ORDER_LINE>
       <NAME>DETAIL</NAME>
       <QTY>1</QTY>
       <LINE_NO>2</LINE_NO>
      </ORDER_LINE>
      <ORDER_LINE>
       <NAME>DETAIL</NAME>
       <QTY>2</QTY>
       <LINE_NO>3</LINE_NO>
      </ORDER_LINE>
  </ORDER>
  <ORDER>
   <NAME>HEADER</NAME>
   <ORDER_NO>200</ORDER_NO>
   <ADDRESS>Posted</ADDRESS>
       <ORDER_LINE>
       <NAME>DETAIL</NAME>
       <QTY>3</QTY>
       <LINE_NO>1</LINE_NO>
      </ORDER_LINE>
      <ORDER_LINE>
       <NAME>DETAIL</NAME>
       <LINE_NO>1</LINE_NO>
       <QTY>3</QTY>
      </ORDER_LINE>
  </ORDER>
</MESSAGE>
```

Can anyone help me to transform this using XSLT 1.0?

Comment: How are the `detail` and `header` nodes related to each other? Please share the XSLT you have tried so far.

Comment: The relationship is such that all the nodes (containing Name = DETAIL) that are below Name = HEADER are considered as details nodes.